# Applescript. Name of the windows in Firefox

Tags: applescript

I want to know the mane of the windows and tabs in Firefox. The things that work well with other browsers give problems here. For instance:

```
tell application "Firefox" to get the name of every window
```

In the Firefox browser, I have a window with apple.com and another window with google.com but the script gives me that strange result:

```
{"Google", "Apple", "", "", "Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more", "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?redirect_source=firefox-com", "", "", ""}
```

That Amazon and mozilla names are previous windows that I am sure that are closed. It also shows several "" I do not know where they come from.

If I go to the doc and I click to Firefox it says that I have two windows open:

```
Apple
Google
```

So, I do not understand the result of the script. Why it gives me more information.

How can I get the name of the windows open in Firefox (including tabs, if possible)

Comment: Firefox doesn't provide a comprehensive _AppleScript Dictionary_ ([see here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=939528)). It provides the bare minimum _Standard Suite_ , (i.e. `window`, `open`, `quit` commands etc). Probably closest you can get to your requirement is to also include an additional qualifier that checks another property, (such as the value of `visible`, or `titled` is `true`). For instance:  `tell application "Firefox" to name of windows whose titled is true`. This reports the name of the active tab in each window only, but not every tab too. Omits some of the cruft !

Comment: @RobC Thank you. I do not see any difference between the option that you provides and the one I first talk about: tell application "Firefox" to get the name of every window Do you think it is better for any reason?

Comment: I firstly utilized `tell application "Firefox" to properties of windows` and done some brief analysis of the result, and concluded that all the cruft that I didn't want returned, (i.e. those windows that were returned yet they didn't actually exist), had their `visible` or `titled` properties set to `false` - which was contrary to those I did want returned as they had those properties set to `true` . So, when I utilized `tell application "Firefox" to name of windows whose titled is true` (or same with `... visible is true`) it didn't return the cruft. Perhaps we have different FF versions.

Comment: So no, I do not think it is particularly better it just improved the result somewhat for me.

Comment: Perhaps consider scripting the GUI using _"System Events"_,-  Firefox does have keyboard shortcuts such as `alt` + `cmd` followed by right/left arrow key to switch between tabs, Windows can also be chosen via the `Windows` menu. However scripting the GUI is a last resort for me because the GUI changes between product releases is often frequent, thus resulting in a brittle solution and a ongoing code maintenance nightmare. I conclude that due to the lack of Firefox providing a comprehensive AppleScript Dictionary any potential solution will most likely be a kludge.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround to get the name of all Firefox tabs.  It ain't pretty :)

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "1" using command down
    set firstTitle to name of front window
    
    set tabList to {}
    set myTitle to "__f_o_o_b_a_r__" -- some random initial name
    set counter to 0                 -- make sure that loop ends

    repeat until (counter > 100 or myTitle is equal to firstTitle)
        tell application "System Events" to key code 121 using control down
        delay 0.05
        set myTitle to (name of front window)
        copy myTitle to the end of the |tabList|
        set counter to counter + 1
    end repeat
end tell

tabList
```

I use a similar approach when [searching for tabs using a global shortcut](https://gist.github.com/henrik242/4e64e208a184f540a80a343187e075c1).

Comment: This is an interesting workaround, unfortunately it does not produce consistent results depending on which _tab_ is currently selected on a multi-tabbed _window_. Also, the _list_ it returns, the _names_ are not in _tab_ order of the _window_.